# Custom UISwitch inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uicontrol

I've implemented a really simple custom UISwitch that uses touches events like:

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I can use this control in my views without problem. The Control simulates a UISwitch, so it can change value through a drag or through a tap.

My problem is that I can't let this Control work inside a Cell of a UITableView. Only the single tap seems to work (note that I'm not using gesture... but the events that I've previously listed) but I can't "swipe" the switch handle.

I instantiate the controller within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method adding the control as subview of the cell `contentView`:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:customSwitch];
```

I suppose that it is something related with the fact that UITableView is a UIScrollView and I think that touches events get somehow "stolen" by it.

// EDIT --------------------

Here is the code related with the Touch events.

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];

    self.dragged = NO;

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.enabled) {
        return NO;
    }

    [super continueTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
    self.dragged = YES;
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    float centerPoint = FIXED_WIDTH / 2.0;

    [self centerOn:(touchPoint.x > centerPoint) animated:YES completion:nil];

    return YES;
}

- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super endTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    BOOL currentOn = self.on;
    BOOL nextOn;

    if (self.dragged) {
        float centerPoint = FIXED_WIDTH / 2.0;
        nextOn = (touchPoint.x > centerPoint);

        [self setOn:nextOn animated:NO];
    }else{
        nextOn = !self.on;
        [self setOn:nextOn animated:YES];
    }
    self.dragged = NO;

    if (currentOn != nextOn) {
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}
```

How can I make the control work inside a Cell without interfering with the UIScrollView/UITableView?

Comment: Have you considered using tap and pan gestures?

Comment: @Wain I prefer to use the Touch events. Does it make difference in this case?

Comment: Look through other questions like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350041/uicontrol-not-receiving-touches

Comment: @Wain I have this problem only if I put the Switch inside a UITableViewCell.

Comment: @gabbler I've added all the code for the touch events. But I just want to mention that this control works has problem only when used inside a UITableViewCell (so I suppose the problem is related with the ScrollView)

Comment: Is Switch a subview of UIControl or UISwitch. No `centerOn` method implementation is found

Comment: Try to set your custom switch as cell's accessory view

Comment: @MatterGoal: Have you checked the UISwitch frame, or any other views are on the switch ?

Comment: @MatterGoal Have you looked into `shouldRespondSimultaneously` and friends on `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`? You might need to implement that in your switch to make sure it triggers together with the scroll https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

Comment: I have also created a substitute for `UISwitch`, and I found it a lot easier to implement a single `UITapGestureRecognizer` than to track touches. I didn't even have to implement a pan recognizer, and it still works with both taps and swipes. I have put this control into `UITableViewCell` instances without issue. I would encourage you to at least give this method a try. It can't take more than an hour to fork the control and reimplement it with gesture recognizers.

Comment: Also, I'm concerned that you're instantiating this control in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is **NOT** where this should occur. You should do this in `init` or `initWithCoder:` in the `UITableViewCell` subclass. If not, you run the risk of adding a new instance of this control every time your `UITableView` recycles a cell.

Comment: @mbm29414 You are right but at the moment I've just a few rows and the cells never need to get recreated.

Comment: @Rick I'm not using gestures.

Comment: @VineeshTP yes, all the frames/Sizes/Bounds/ are correct.

Comment: @MatterGoal That is not a good reason for poor design. If, for some reason, you suddenly need to have more cells than the screen can display, you have to completely refactor this code. Much easier to avoid that (potentially) elusive bug by getting the architecture right at the outset.

Comment: I totally agree with you. This is just a prototype app to test this component... I'll never write something like that in a "real" app. Thank you to be so rigid.

Comment: @MatterGoal: Is there any view overlap on the switch / if you are accessing with tag, check the tags are correct.

Comment: @VineeshTP there aren't other views above the cell

Comment: you didn't share any code from tableviewCell, please share code in tableViewCellForIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your custom switch using gestures instead of trying to directly process events.

The gesture recognizers work behind the scenes to coordinate their event processing which, for example, is why a UIScrollView can work inside of another UIScrollView. You need that coordination for the UITableView (really a UIScrollView) to properly handle swipe gestures within its content.

Search the web for Hardy Macia's UICustomSwitch sample code for a good example of matching the UISwitch behaviors in a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:`?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    // Get the only touch (multipleTouchEnabled is NO)
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    // Track the touch
    [self beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    // Get the only touch (multipleTouchEnabled is NO)
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    // Track the touch
    [self continueTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: To the Down-voter: Care to explain why the down-vote?

Comment: Are you sure that functions are needed? I can make the switch work with no problem outside the cell.

Comment: Also try implementing `sendActionsForControlEvents:` in `beginTrackingWithTouch` and `continueTrackingWithTouch`. To be specific: `[self sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];` and `[self sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside]` respectively.

Comment: @MatterGoal I did read it. Maybe you overlooked my comment above. Try adding `[self sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];` and `[self sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside]` in **YOUR** beginTracking and continueTracking methods. I implemented these in my project and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Sorry I've totally overlooked your comment