# Delegates in swift?

Tags: delegates, swift, delegation

How does one go about making a delegate, i.e. `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in swift?

Comment: Do you mean implementing a delegate or defining your own delegate?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It is not that different from obj-c.
First, you have to specify the protocol in your class declaration, like following:

```
class MyClass: NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

The implementation will look like following:

```
// NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate implementation
func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didDeliverNotification notification: NSUserNotification) {
    //implementation
}

func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivateNotification notification: NSUserNotification) {
    //implementation
}

func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresentNotification notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
    //implementation
    return true
}
```

Of course, you have to set the delegate. For example:

```
NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().delegate = self;
```

Comment: What happens when you want to extend UIViewController, for example, in objective-c, you can have something lie this `@interface MyCustomClass: UIViewController <ClassIWantToUseDelegate>`, allowing you to init/configure the viewcontroller, as well as call delegate methods on the subviews? Something similar to [this](https://demo.firepad.io/#I5SeULDewr)?

Comment: Hi Adam, quick question, how can I set delegate = self, if I cannot instantiate an object because it is a generic class which I don't have access to in the other class, yet I want the generics class to call a function in the other class, hence the need for delegate?

Answer (score 251):

Here's a little help on delegates between two view controllers:

**Step 1:** Make a protocol in the UIViewController that you will be removing/will be sending the data.

```
protocol FooTwoViewControllerDelegate:class {
    func myVCDidFinish(_ controller: FooTwoViewController, text: String)
}
```

**Step2:**  Declare the delegate in the sending class (i.e. UIViewcontroller)

```
class FooTwoViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: FooTwoViewControllerDelegate?
    [snip...]
}
```

**Step3:**  Use the delegate in a class method to send the data to the receiving method, which is any method that adopts the protocol.

```
@IBAction func saveColor(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        delegate?.myVCDidFinish(self, text: colorLabel.text) //assuming the delegate is assigned otherwise error
}
```

**Step 4:** Adopt the protocol in the receiving class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FooTwoViewControllerDelegate {
```

**Step 5:** Implement the delegate method

```
func myVCDidFinish(_ controller: FooTwoViewController, text: String) {
    colorLabel.text = "The Color is " +  text
    controller.navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

**Step 6:** Set the delegate in the prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! FooTwoViewController
        vc.colorString = colorLabel.text
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

And that should work. This is of course just code fragments, but should give you the idea. For a long explanation of this code you can go over to my blog entry here:

[segues and delegates](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/)

If you are interested in what's going on under the hood with a delegate I did write on that here:

[under the hood with delegates](http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/04/the-swift-swift-tutorial-why-do-we-need-delegates/)

Comment: Step2 shouldyn't be there weak reference to delegate ? 
if I'm I right please edit it. Btw you can make it optional value. That would be more swift.
weak var delegate:FooTwoViewControllerDelegate?

PS: delegate should be weak cus of retain circle, child shouldynt keep strong reference to parent

Comment: In my way when you will make delegate optional you will resolve you unwraping error.
delegate?.myVCDidFinish          Becouse if delegate is not set the cod wont execute now :) 
In your version it will try to execute and will fail to unwrap if delegate is nil and you it is.

Comment: you need to declare protocol like this in order to make weak reference possible for delegate protocol FooTwoViewControllerDelegate:class{}

Comment: Could you please set by each step in which VC you are like VC1 and VC2. I am not really sure where to put them.

Comment: @Shial - Actually it appears to be a little complicated.  `weak` is only needed for classes not structs and enums.  If the delegate is going to be a struct or enum then you don't need to worry about retain cycles.  However, the delegate its a class (this is true for a lot of cases since quite often its a ViewController), then you need `weak` but you need to declare your protocol as a class.  There is more info here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34566876/296446

Answer (score 124):

Delegates always confused me until I realized that **a delegate is just a class that does some work for another class**. It's like having someone else there to do all the dirty work for you that you don't want to do yourself.

I wrote a little story to illustrate this. Read it in a Playground if you like.

## Once upon a time...

```
// MARK: Background to the story

// A protocol is like a list of rules that need to be followed.
protocol OlderSiblingDelegate: class {
    // The following command (ie, method) must be obeyed by any 
    // underling (ie, delegate) of the older sibling.
    func getYourNiceOlderSiblingAGlassOfWater()
}

// MARK: Characters in the story

class BossyBigBrother {
    
    // I can make whichever little sibling is around at 
    // the time be my delegate (ie, slave)
    weak var delegate: OlderSiblingDelegate?
    
    func tellSomebodyToGetMeSomeWater() {
        // The delegate is optional because even though 
        // I'm thirsty, there might not be anyone nearby 
        // that I can boss around.
        delegate?.getYourNiceOlderSiblingAGlassOfWater()
    }
}

// Poor little sisters have to follow (or at least acknowledge) 
// their older sibling's rules (ie, protocol)
class PoorLittleSister: OlderSiblingDelegate {

    func getYourNiceOlderSiblingAGlassOfWater() {
        // Little sis follows the letter of the law (ie, protocol),
        // but no one said exactly how she had to respond.
        print("Go get it yourself!")
    }
}

// MARK: The Story

// Big bro is laying on the couch watching basketball on TV.
let bigBro = BossyBigBrother()

// He has a little sister named Sally.
let sally = PoorLittleSister()

// Sally walks into the room. How convenient! Now big bro 
// has someone there to boss around.
bigBro.delegate = sally

// So he tells her to get him some water.
bigBro.tellSomebodyToGetMeSomeWater()

// Unfortunately no one lived happily ever after...

// The end.
```

In review, there are three key parts to making and using the delegate pattern.

1. the **protocol** that defines what the worker needs to do
2. the **boss class** that has a delegate variable, which it uses to tell the worker class what to do
3. the **worker class** that adopts the protocol and does what is required

## Real life

In comparison to our Bossy Big Brother story above, delegates are often used for the following practical applications:

1. **Communication**: one class needs to send some information to another class.

   - Code example 1: [sending data from one view controller to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33229483/3681880)
   - Code example 2: [sending text input from a custom keyboard to a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33692231/3681880)
2. **Customization**: one class wants to allow another class to customize it.

The great part is that these classes don't need to know anything about each other beforehand except that the delegate class conforms to the required protocol.

I highly recommend reading the following two articles. They helped me understand delegates even better than the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) did.

- [What is Delegation? – A Swift Developer’s Guide](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/26/what-is-delegation-a-swift-developers-guide/)
- [How Delegation Works – A Swift Developer’s Guide](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/)

**One more note**

Delegates that reference other classes that they do not own should use the `weak` keyword to avoid strong reference cycles. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34566876/3681880) for more details.

Comment: Finally someone that can explain protocol and delegate with common sense! thanks man!

Comment: What happens when Bossy Big Brother doesn't know he's a brother (Generics) ?

Comment: @Marin, I'm not really sure that I understand your question. The list of rules (protocol) doesn't care who it is that is calling for the rules to be followed or who is following the rules. They are just rules.

Comment: Basically I am referring to my question,  slightly simplified over here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195203/swift-3-delegate-within-tapgesturerecognizer-in-generics-doesnt-get-called

Answer (score 48):

I got few corrections to post of @MakeAppPie

First at all when you are creating delegate protocol it should conform to Class protocol. Like in example below.

```
protocol ProtocolDelegate: class {
    func myMethod(controller:ViewController, text:String)
}
```

Second, your delegate should be weak to avoid retain cycle.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ProtocolDelegate?
}
```

Last, you're safe because your protocol is an optional value. That means its "nil" message will be not send to this property. It's similar to conditional statement with `respondToselector` in objC but here you have everything in one line:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod:text:)]) {
    [self.delegate myMethod:self text:@"you Text"];
}
```

Above you have an obj-C example and below you have Swift example of how it looks.

```
delegate?.myMethod(self, text:"your Text")
```

Comment: *you're safe because your protocol is an optional value*..... because you you use optional chaining `delegate?.myMethod` won't crash because if delegate is `nil` then nothing would happen. However if you made mistake and wrote `delegate!.myMethod` you *could* crash if a delegate is not set, so its basically a way for you to be safe...

Answer (score 35):

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/derrickshowers/80fb450490ff03e6e274) I put together. I was wondering the same and this helped improve my understanding. Open this up in an [Xcode Playground](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=24) to see what's going on.

```
protocol YelpRequestDelegate {
    func getYelpData() -> AnyObject
    func processYelpData(data: NSData) -> NSData
}

class YelpAPI {
    var delegate: YelpRequestDelegate?

    func getData() {
        println("data being retrieved...")
        let data: AnyObject? = delegate?.getYelpData()
    }

    func processYelpData(data: NSData) {
        println("data being processed...")
        let data = delegate?.processYelpData(data)
    }
}

class Controller: YelpRequestDelegate {
    init() {
        var yelpAPI = YelpAPI()
        yelpAPI.delegate = self
        yelpAPI.getData()
    }
    func getYelpData() -> AnyObject {
        println("getYelpData called")
        return NSData()
    }
    func processYelpData(data: NSData) -> NSData {
        println("processYelpData called")
        return NSData()
    }
}

var controller = Controller()
```

Comment: Love this. Very helpful

Comment: @SeeMeCode Hi, It was good example firstly, but i still have an issue. How can i make my any `UIViewController` class to conform delegate we made?
Are they have to be declared in one swift file? Any help will mean a lot.

Comment: @Faruk It's been awhile since I posted this, but I think what you're asking should be pretty simple (If I'm misunderstanding, I apologize). Just add the delegate to your UIViewController after the colon. So something like `class ViewController : UIViewController NameOfDelegate`.

Comment: @SeeMeCode yes, you got my question well. I tried your suggestion btw, but when I create a delegate class in `a.swift` according to your answer above, it doesn't come up in `b.swift`. I cannot reach any class outside of my swift file. any toughts?

Comment: one thing i don't understand is why should I create a new instance of YelpApi just so that i call YelpApi's delegate ?  What if the instance that's running is different from the 'new' one I just created... how does it know which delegate belongs to which instance of YelpApi ?

Answer (score 18):

**DELEGATES IN SWIFT 2**

I am explaining with example of Delegate with two viewControllers.In this case, SecondVC Object is sending data back to first View Controller.

Class with Protocol Declaration

```
protocol  getDataDelegate  {
    func getDataFromAnotherVC(temp: String)
}


import UIKit
class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    var delegateCustom : getDataDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func backToMainVC(sender: AnyObject) {
      //calling method defined in first View Controller with Object  
      self.delegateCustom?.getDataFromAnotherVC(temp: "I am sending data from second controller to first view controller.Its my first delegate example. I am done with custom delegates.")
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    
}
```

In First ViewController Protocol conforming is done here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, getDataDelegate
```

Protocol method definition in First View Controller(ViewController)

```
func getDataFromAnotherVC(temp : String)
{
  // dataString from SecondVC
   lblForData.text = dataString
}
```

During push the SecondVC from First View Controller (ViewController)

```
let objectPush = SecondVC()
objectPush.delegateCustom = self
self.navigationController.pushViewController(objectPush, animated: true)
```

Comment: Your last 3 lines helped me to understand my scenario and solved my issue. Thanks Man! :)

Comment: Working For Men.....

Answer (score 6):

First class:

```
protocol NetworkServiceDelegate: class {
        
    func didCompleteRequest(result: String)
}


class NetworkService: NSObject {

    weak var delegate: NetworkServiceDelegate?
    
    func fetchDataFromURL(url : String) {
        delegate?.didCompleteRequest(result: url)
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NetworkServiceDelegate {
    
    let network = NetworkService()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        network.delegate = self
        network.fetchDataFromURL(url: "Success!")
    }

 
    
    func didCompleteRequest(result: String) {
        print(result)
    }


}
```

Comment: on compiling above code it shows error `Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'NetworkServiceDelegate'` plz suggest. It is my 6th day on swift :)

Answer (score 4):

**Very easy step by step (100% working and tested)**

**step1:** Create method on first view controller

```
 func updateProcessStatus(isCompleted : Bool){
    if isCompleted{
        self.labelStatus.text = "Process is completed"
    }else{
        self.labelStatus.text = "Process is in progress"
    }
}
```

**step2:** Set delegate while push to second view controller

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController
    secondViewController.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

**step3:** set delegate like

class ViewController: UIViewController,**ProcessStatusDelegate** {

**step4:** Create protocol

```
protocol ProcessStatusDelegate:NSObjectProtocol{
func updateProcessStatus(isCompleted : Bool)
}
```

**step5:** take a variable

```
var delegate:ProcessStatusDelegate?
```

**step6:** While go back to previous view controller call delegate method so first view controller notify with data

```
@IBAction func buttonActionBack(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.updateProcessStatus(isCompleted: true)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

@IBAction func buttonProgress(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.updateProcessStatus(isCompleted: false)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Example:**

```
protocol Work: class {
    func doSomething()
}

class Manager {
    weak var delegate: Work?
    func passAlong() {
        delegate?.doSomething()
    }
}

class Employee: Work {
    func doSomething() {
        print("Working on it")
    }
}

let manager = Manager()
let developer = Employee()
manager.delegate = developer
manager.passAlong() // PRINTS: Working on it
```

Comment: why do u use keyword "class" in the protocol description? what's the difference in using and not using it?

Comment: The class keyword means it's a class only protocol. You can limit protocol adoption to class types, and not structures or enumerations, by adding the class keyword. I probably should not have added it to avoid any confusion, but since you asked I will keep.

Answer (score 3):

**Here Simple Code Example of Delegate:**

```
//MARK: - Protocol ShowResult
protocol ShowResult: AnyObject {
       func show(value: Int) 
  }

//MARK: - MyOperation Class
class MyOperation {
weak var delegate: ShowResult?

func sum(fNumber: Int, sNumber: Int) {
    delegate?.show(value: fNumber + sNumber)
  }
}

//MARK: - ViewController Class
class ViewController: UIViewController,ShowResult {
var myOperation: MyOperation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadMyOperation()
    myOperation?.delegate = self
    myOperation?.sum(fNumber: 100, sNumber: 20)
 }

private func loadMyOperation() {
    if myOperation == nil {
        myOperation = MyOperation()
     }
 }

func show(value: Int) {
    print("value: \(value)")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Delegates are a design pattern that allows one object to send messages to another object when a specific event happens.
Imagine an object A calls an object B to perform an action. Once the action is complete, object A should know that B has completed the task and take necessary action, this can be achieved with the help of delegates!
Here is a tutorial implementing delegates step by step in swift 3

[Tutorial Link](https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef#.vvdx9admt)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is real life delegate scenario**
Lets make our own UITextField and UITextFieldDelegate

```
// THE MYSTERIOUS UITEXTFIELD

protocol UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void
}

class UITextField {
    var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate?
    private var mText: String?
    var text: String? {
        get {
            return mText
        }
    }
    
    init(text: String) {
        
    }
    
    init() {
        
    }
    
    func setText(_ text: String) {
        mText = text
        delegate?.textFieldDidChange(self)
    }

}
```

```
// HERE IS MY APP

class Main {
    
    let textfield = UITextField()
    
    func viewDidLoad() {
        print("viewDidLoad")
        textfield.delegate = self
        textfield.setText("Hello")
    }
    
}

extension Main: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.text ?? "No string")
    }
    
}

let main = Main()
main.viewDidLoad()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above seemed a little coupled and at the same time avoid reuse the same protocol in other controllers, that's why I've come with the solution that is more strong typed using generic type-erasure.

```
@noreturn public func notImplemented(){
    fatalError("not implemented yet")
}


public protocol DataChangedProtocol: class{
    typealias DataType

    func onChange(t:DataType)
}

class AbstractDataChangedWrapper<DataType> : DataChangedProtocol{

    func onChange(t: DataType) {
        notImplemented()
    }
}


class AnyDataChangedWrapper<T: DataChangedProtocol> : AbstractDataChangedWrapper<T.DataType>{

    var base: T

    init(_ base: T ){
        self.base = base
    }

    override func onChange(t: T.DataType) {
        base.onChange(t)
    }
}


class AnyDataChangedProtocol<DataType> : DataChangedProtocol{

    var base: AbstractDataChangedWrapper<DataType>

    init<S: DataChangedProtocol where S.DataType == DataType>(_ s: S){
        self.base = AnyDataChangedWrapper(s)
    }

    func onChange(t: DataType) {
        base.onChange(t)
    }
}



class Source : DataChangedProtocol {
    func onChange(data: String) {
        print( "got new value \(data)" )
    }
}


class Target {
    var delegate: AnyDataChangedProtocol<String>?

    func reportChange(data:String ){
        delegate?.onChange(data)
    }
}


var source = Source()
var target = Target()

target.delegate = AnyDataChangedProtocol(source)
target.reportChange("newValue")
```

**output**: *got new value newValue*

Comment: I'm interested in learning more about this. Can you explain more about the terms you use: coupled, "avoid reuse the same protocol", "generic type-erasure". Why is abstracting it like this important? Should one always do this?

Answer (score 0):

### In swift 4.0

Create a delegate on class that need to send some data or provide some functionality to other classes

Like

```
protocol GetGameStatus {
    var score: score { get }
    func getPlayerDetails()
}
```

After that in the class that going to confirm to this delegate

```
class SnakesAndLadders: GetGameStatus {
    func getPlayerDetails() {

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### In swift 5

###### I am a beginner, I think this is easiest way to understand in practical scenario

Note:Any improvisations are most appreciated

```
protocol APIService {
   func onSuccessResponse() -> AnyObject
   func onFailureResponse() -> AnyObject
}

class APIHelper{

var delegate : APIService?

func postUsersDataAPI() {
    //assuming API communication is success
    if(success){
       let _: AnyObject? = delegate?.onSuccessResponse()
    }else if(failure){
       let _: AnyObject? = delegate?.onFailureResponse()
  }
 }

func getAllUsersAPI() {
    //assuming API communication is success
   if(success){
       let _: AnyObject? = delegate?.onSuccessResponse()
    }else if(failure){
       let _: AnyObject? = delegate?.onFailureResponse()
  }
 }
}


class ViewController:UIViewController,APIService {

func onSuccessResponse() -> AnyObject {
    print("onSuccessResponse") as AnyObject
}

func onFailureResponse() -> AnyObject {
    print("onFailureResponse") as AnyObject
}

@IBAction func clickBtnToPostUserData(_ sender: Any) { 
    let apiHelper = APIHelper()
    apiHelper.delegate = self
    apiHelper.postAPI()
}
```