# Implement a protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

I am using an Objective-C library. It has a protocol as

```
@protocol RNFrostedSidebarDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)sidebar:(RNFrostedSidebar *)sidebar didTapItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)sidebar:(RNFrostedSidebar *)sidebar didEnable:(BOOL)itemEnabled itemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

I am trying to implement it in Swift. How should I write this `func`?

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24099437/730701).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this would be a Swift class implementing the protocol

```
class MyForstedSidebarDelegate : RNFrostedSidebarDelegate {

    func sidebar(sidebar: RNFrostedSidebar, didTapItemAtIndex index: UInt) {
        ... do stuff ...
    }

    func sidebar(sidebar: RNFrostedSidebar, didEnable itemEnabled: Bool, itemAtIndex index: UInt) {
        ... do stuff ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this could be similar to your original concept:

```
@objc protocol RNFrostedSidebarDelegate {
    @optional func sideBarDidTapItem(sidebar: RNFrostedSidebar, index: UInt) -> ()
    @optional func sideBarDidEnable(sidebar: RNFrostedSidebar, itemEnabled: Bool, index: UInt) -> ()
}
```