# How do I declare a variable that has a type and implements a protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

My app has a protocol for detail view controllers, stating they must have a `viewModel` property:

```
protocol DetailViewController: class {
    var viewModel: ViewModel? {get set}
}
```

I also have a few different classes that implement the protocol:

```
class FormViewController: UITableViewController, DetailViewController {
    // ...
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController, DetailViewController {
    // ...
}
```

My master view controller needs a property that can be set to any `UIViewController` subclass that implements the `DetailViewController` protocol.

Unfortunately I can't find any documentation on how to do this. In Objective-C it would be trivial:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController<DetailViewController>;
```

It appears that there isn't any syntax available in Swift to do this. The closest I've come is to declare a generic in my class definition:

```
class MasterViewController<T where T:UIViewController, T:DetailViewController>: UITableViewController {
    var detailViewController: T?
    // ...
}
```

But then I get an error saying that "Class 'MasterViewController' does not implement its superclass's required members"

This seems like it should be as easy to do in Swift as it is in Objective-C, but I can't find anything anywhere that suggests how I might go about it.

Comment: What init methods are present in MasterViewController ?

Comment: I've posted a solution to this on http://stackoverflow.com/a/35069853/1316462

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Swift 4, you can now do this.

Swift 4 implemented [SE-0156](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) (Class and Subtype existentials).

The equivalent of this Objective-C syntax:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController<DetailViewController> * detailViewController;
```

Now looks like this in Swift 4:

```
var detailViewController: UIViewController & DetailViewController
```

Essentially you get to define one class that the variable conforms to, and N number of protocols it implements. See the linked document for more detailed information.

Answer (score 13):

I think you can get there by adding an (empty) extension to `UIViewController` and then specifying your `detailViewController` attribute using a composed protocol of the empty extension and your `DetailViewController`.  Like this:

```
protocol UIViewControllerInject {}
extension UIViewController : UIViewControllerInject {}
```

Now all subclasses of `UIViewController` satisfy protocol `UIViewControllerInject`.  Then with that, simply:

```
typealias DetailViewControllerComposed = protocol<DetailViewController, UIViewControllerInject>

class MasterViewController : UITableViewController {
  var detailViewController : DetailViewControllerComposed?
  // ...
}
```

But, this is not particularly 'natural'.

**=== Edit, Addition ===**

Actually, you could make it a bit better if you define your `DetailViewController` using my suggested `UIViewControllerInject`.  Like such:

```
protocol UIViewControllerInject {}
extension UIViewController : UIViewControllerInject {}

protocol DetailViewController : UIViewControllerInject { /* ... */ }
```

and now you don't need to explicitly compose something (my `DetailViewControllerComposed`) and can use `DetailViewController?` as the type for `detailViewController`.

Comment: I'm not super thrilled that every UIViewController subclass is going to have a viewModel property, but it at least gets things compiling :)

Comment: No, I'm not saying that.  The protocol added to UIViewController _is an empty one_!

Comment: @FrankSchmitt , what if I want `var detailViewController: DetailViewController ` to be a subclass of `UIViewController` strictly? Just as clear as the declaration `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController<DetailViewController> detailViewController;` in Objective-C. Is it possible for Swift to do this?

Comment: This solves the issue one-way - but then when you have `UIViewControllerInject` passed somewhere in the code, you cannot call any `UIViewController` method on it without force-casting (`as!`). Unfortunately, I believe there is no way currently to declare a variable to be of a certain class conforming to a certain protocol as is possible in ObjC. You can, of course, declare all methods that you need from `UIViewController` in the `UIViewControllerInject` protocol.

Comment: This is [now possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46386005/35690) as of Swift 4.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to introduce intermediate base classes for the appropriate UIKit view controllers that implement the protocol:

```
class MyUIViewControler : UIViewController, DetailViewController ...
class MyUITableViewController : UITableViewController, DetailViewController ...
```

Then you inherit your view controllers from these view controllers, not the UIKit ones.

This is not natural either, but it doesn't force all your `UIViewControllers` to satisfy the `UIViewControllerInject` protocol as GoZoner suggested.

Comment: I'd go that route but I'm not sure how to declare a property that can be either of type `MyUIViewController` or `MyUITableViewController`.