# Define a variable which conforms to a protocol and inherits from a class in Swift

Tags: swift, casting

In Objective-C, I can do the following:

```
SomeClass<SomeProtocol> *foo = nil;
```

This tells the compiler that `foo` isa `SomeClass`, and conforms to the protocol `SomeProtocol`.

How can I do the same thing in Swift?

When I try to do the following:

```
@objc
protocol SomeProtocol {}

class SomeClass: NSObject {}

class ChildClass: SomeClass, SomeProtocol {}

class FooBar {
    init() {
        var foo: SomeClass<SomeProtocol>

    }
}
```

... it gives the error:

```
error: cannot specialize non-generic type 'SomeClass'
        var foo: SomeClass<SomeProtocol>
                 ^
```

This is because angel brackets (`<>`) are reserved for generics rather than protocols.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? – [How do I declare a variable that has a type and implements a protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214484/how-do-i-declare-a-variable-that-has-a-type-and-implements-a-protocol)