# How do I check when a UITextField changes?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to check when a text field changes, equivalent too the function used for textView - `textViewDidChange` so far I have done this:

```
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if self.status.text == "" && self.username.text == "" {
            self.topRightButton.enabled = false
        } else {   
            self.topRightButton.enabled = true
        }
    }
```

Which kind of works, but the `topRightButton` is enabled as soon as the text field is pressed on, I want it to be enabled only when text is actually typed in?

Answer (score 895, accepted):

**SWIFT**

**Swift 4.2**

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

}
```

**SWIFT 3 & swift 4.1**

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

}
```

**SWIFT 2.2**

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

and

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    //your code
}
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and textFieldDidChange method is

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: This crashes for me and I don't understand why.

Comment: Checked multiple times. Delegate is set immediately before it inside `viewDidLoad`. The action is letter for letter the same. The app crashes as soon as a keyboard button is pressed.

Edit: Figured it out! Was missing the semicolon inside the action. I assumed it only had to be same as the function name.

Comment: @FawadMasud this does nothing now in Swift 2.0 on iOS 9 with XCode 7 has it been depreciated or do you know the current way to fix it?

Comment: @CodyWeaver I just checked it on XCode 7, iOS 9 and it is working fine. Make sure there are no spelling mistakes in the function you are naming.

Comment: @FawadMasud yeah it worked fine. How can I call this method or `textFieldDidEndEditing` if I change the `UITextField`'s text from another object?

Comment: @CodyWeaver you can use delegates or you can use notifications.

Comment: The `UITextField`'s delegate is itself.

Comment: @CodyWeaver No I am not talking about UITextField's delegate. You have to create your own delegate methods in the current class and call these methods from the other class.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift

Comment: Target/Action and Delegates are two totally different ways to get the action.

Comment: I had to change the code for Swift to `textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)` to make it work.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe that is for swift 2.2. I will update it for swift 2.2 as well. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @FawadMasud   Usually you don't have a single textField in a view. How can I refer to all textFields and then addTarget(self, action:) ? Should I loop through all textFileds that are in the View and inside the for loop do nameOfTextField.addTarget(self, action:...) Is there a less verbose way?

Comment: @bibscy yes you have to loop through all textfields inside a view.

Comment: For Swift 4.2 its:
 Texttfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewControllerr.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)

Comment: For Swift 4.2 there's a warning not to use @objc which you need when you use #selector.  So, what's the real solution for Swift 4.2/XCode 10?

Comment: Update: @Exitare, swift does not require the ViewController. in the #selector.  This changed happened in later swift 3.x.
What is needed for mine to work was to add the UITextFieldDelegate to the class and add textField.delegate = self.

Comment: I know and changed my usage but I totally forgot to change my answer here.

Comment: Does not called on TextField Clear Button press.

Comment: @Argus you need to subclass `UITextField` and override `deleteBackward` method

Comment: Several years later note: This _does not_ get called when you set the text field's text programmatically (`textField.text = "something"`). If you're setting a text programmatically (like auto-formatting and stuff), you would need to call this method manually. It only gets called automatically in response to the user typing in the actual keyboard (because `.editingChanged` only gets triggered automatically in this case).

Answer (score 154):

You can make this connection in interface builder.

1. In your storyboard, click the assistant editor at the top of the screen (two circles in the middle).
   [image: Assistant editor selected]
2. Ctrl + Click on the textfield in interface builder.
3. Drag from EditingChanged to inside your view controller class in the assistant view.
   [image: Making connection]
4. Name your function ("textDidChange" for example) and click connect.
   [image: Naming function]

Comment: This is a great solution especially especially if dealing with a UITextField in a tableViewCell that is being managed by a separate datasource. This approach allows the viewController to respond directly (thus the datasource doesn't have to respond and delegate the action).

Comment: Great - a simple solution to an irritating issue. You can of course link multiple textfield

Comment: Probably a better answer than above because eliminating addition @objc func.

Comment: Good Idea , I use event DidEndEditing

Comment: This is the best solution. Thanks @rmooney!

Comment: This should be the best and recommended approach. The simplest one.

Comment: Using IBActions is much easier, this should probably be the top answer

Answer (score 91):

## **Swift 5.0**

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)),
                          for: .editingChanged)
```

and handle method:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

}
```

## **Swift 4.0**

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)),
                          for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

and handle method:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

}
```

## **Swift 3.0**

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and handle method:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) { 

}
```

Answer (score 41):

The way I've handled it so far: in  `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    // text hasn't changed yet, you have to compute the text AFTER the edit yourself
    let updatedString = (textField.text as NSString?)?.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    // do whatever you need with this updated string (your code)


    // always return true so that changes propagate
    return true
}
```

Swift4 version

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let updatedString = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    return true
}
```

Comment: This will not be called when a  textfield is empty and the user click backspace.

Answer (score 14):

Swift 3

```
 textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

Answer (score 10):

[textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield) worked for me in Xcode 8, Swift 3 if you want to check every single keypress.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Whatever code you want to run here.
    // Keep in mind that the textfield hasn't yet been updated,
    // so use 'string' instead of 'textField.text' if you want to
    // access the string the textfield will have after a user presses a key

    var statusText = self.status.text
    var usernameText = self.username.text

    switch textField{
    case self.status:
        statusText = string
    case self.username:
        usernameText = string
    default:
        break
    }

    if statusText == "" && usernameText == "" {
        self.topRightButton.enabled = false
    } else {   
        self.topRightButton.enabled = true
    }

    //Return false if you don't want the textfield to be updated
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

Conform to **UITextFieldDelegate**.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // figure out what the new string will be after the pending edit
    let updatedString = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    // Do whatever you want here


    // Return true so that the change happens
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3.0.1+** (Some of the other swift 3.0 answers are not up to date)

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)),
                          for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this delegate method from UITextFieldDelegate. It fires with every character change.

```
(Objective C) textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
(Swift) textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)
```

However THIS ONLY FIRES **BEFORE** a change is made (indeed, a change is only made if you do return true from here).

Comment: How should this be wrote as I have also tried this method and come to the same solution where it only changes once the textField is activated, not once the text actually changes??

Comment: When you implement the above delegate method, it fires every time you change your text. You only need to add this code, self.textfield.delegate = self

Comment: For me, this method didn't work because you couldn't check if the textfield was empty inside the method. Primarily because it returns true/false depending on IF the textfield can change. So the event fires BEFORE the textfield has had a chance to become empty.

Comment: @LeviRoberts, You have a reference to textfield inside this method. So you can check if the textfield.text is empty.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. When it is empty, the `.isEmpty` method does not equate to true until AFTER this method has had a chance to return true; to tell the app that the textfield should change.

Comment: As per the protocol reference;
"Asks the delegate if the specified text should be changed."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Answer (score 3):

**Maybe use RxSwift ?**

need

```
pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 3.0'
pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 3.0'
```

add imports obviously

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
```

So u have a `textfield : UITextField`

```
let observable: Observable<String?> = textField.rx.text.asObservable()
observable.subscribe(
            onNext: {(string: String?) in
                print(string!)
        })
```

*U have other 3 methods..*

1. onError
2. onCompleted
3. onDisposed
4. onNext

Comment: To receive events of real change only and not also when textfield became first responder, you have to use distinctUntilChanged on text.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textIsChanging), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

@objc func textIsChanging(_ textField:UITextField) {

 print ("TextField is changing")

}
```

*If you want to make a change once the user has typed in completely (It will be called once user dismiss keyboard or press enter).*

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidEnd)

 @objc func textDidChange(_ textField:UITextField) {

       print ("TextField did changed") 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

In case it is not possible to bind the addTarget to your UITextField, I advise you to bind one of them as suggested above, and insert the code for execution at the end of the shouldChangeCharactersIn method.

```
nameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RegistrationViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if phoneNumberTextField.text!.count == 17 && nameTextField.text!.count > 0 {
        continueButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(.green)
    } else {
        continueButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = .systemGray
    }
}
```

And in call in shouldChangeCharactersIn func.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let text = textField.text else {
        return true
    }
    let lastText = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as String

    if phoneNumberTextField == textField {
        textField.text = lastText.format("+7(NNN)-NNN-NN-NN", oldString: text)
        textFieldDidChange(phoneNumberTextField)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's now a UITextField delegate method available on iOS13+

```
optional func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField)
```

Comment: This method is regarding selection, not the actual text

Answer (score 2):

You should follow this steps:

1. Make a Outlet reference to the textfield
2. AssignUITextFieldDelegate to the controller class
3. Configure yourTextField.delegate
4. Implement whatever function you need

Sample code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var yourTextFiled : UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        yourTextFiled.delegate = self
    }


    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // your code
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // your code
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txf_Subject.addTarget(self, action:#selector(didChangeFirstText), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func didChangeText(textField:UITextField) {
    let str = textField.text
    if(str?.contains(" "))!{
        let newstr = str?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        textField.text = newstr
    }
}

@objc func didChangeFirstText(textField:UITextField) {
    if(textField.text == " "){
        textField.text = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

write this in viewDidLoad

```
// to detect if TextField changed
TextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)),
                                   for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

write this outside viewDidLoad

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // do something
}
```

You could change the event by UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin or what ever you want to detect.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add a `textField text change listener` using **Swift 3**:

Declare your class as `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.delegate = self

    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UITextFieldDelegate.textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
}
```

Then just traditionally add a textFieldShouldEndEditing function:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { // do stuff
        return true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are interested in a SwiftUI solution, this it's working for me:

```
 TextField("write your answer here...",
            text: Binding(
                     get: {
                        return self.query
                       },
                     set: { (newValue) in
                        self.fetch(query: newValue) // any action you need
                                return self.query = newValue
                      }
            )
  )
```

I have to say it's not my idea, I read it in this blog: [SwiftUI binding: A very simple trick](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-binding-a-very-simple-trick-c975a1abbf9c)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage editing either by "shouldchangecharacter" delgate or "begin and end" textfield delegate. **Don't forget to set delegate**

I am manage to do this using "did begin and end editing" below.

```
//MARK:- TextViewDelegate
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let count = self.tfEmail.text?.count ?? 0
        if textField == self.tfEmail {
            if count == 0{
              //Empty textfield
            }else{
              //Non-Empty textfield
            }
        }
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self.tfEmail{
            //when user taps on textfield
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS 13+** there's `UITextField` **delegate** method available to detect real-time changes in `UITextField`'s text

```
  func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField){
        
        if textField == self.myTextField{
           
          print("\(textField.text)")
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

**swift 4**

In viewDidLoad():

```
    //ADD BUTTON TO DISMISS KEYBOARD

    // Init a keyboard toolbar 
    let toolbar = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height+44, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 44))
    toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    // Add done button
    let doneButt = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: toolbar.frame.size.width - 60, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    doneButt.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    doneButt.setTitleColor(MAIN_COLOR, for: .normal)
    doneButt.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Titillium-Semibold", size: 13)
    doneButt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard), for: .touchUpInside)
    toolbar.addSubview(doneButt)

    USDTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

Add this function:

```
    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
      //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
      view.endEditing(true)
    }
```