# Swift make label overlap status bar

Tags: swift

I have this label in Swift

```
let top_error_rep: UILabel = {
    let lb = UILabel()
    lb.text="Password should be at least 6 charachters"
    lb.textColor = UIColor(r: 230, g: 230, b: 230)
    lb.backgroundColor = .red
    return lb;
}()
```

I show it only when user input is less than 6 characters. Now when I show it status bar overlaps the input, how can I prevent that?

This is how it looks like

[image]

Comment: where did you place the label?

Comment: On the the top of UIview @GaneshKumar

Comment: provide the code and screenshots how its appearing

Comment: @GaneshKumar done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set label's position.

After you add the label to subViews of your view. You need to set it's position by using constraint like this:

```
top_error_rep.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
top_error_rep.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
top_error_rep.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
top_error_rep.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
```

or you can use different way. Google for `Auto layout programmatically swift`

2. Make it only show when user input is less than 6 characters

[How do I check when a UITextField changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-uitextfield-changes)

This may helps you

**EDIT**

add this to your ViewController to hide the status bar

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //Add below line.....
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    //It will show the status bar again after dismiss
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I have added constraints.But i only need my label to overlap status bar

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding your question... I edited my answer