# How to print multiple textfield in center of view programmatically?

Tags: iphone, swift3, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to print multiple textField in middle of the view but I can't. I wanna clickable textfield.textfield should be middle of the view and font size will be manage as textfield size.

This is my code:

```
for i in 0..<characters.count
{
    let textField : UITextField = UITextField(frame : CGRect(x:(charWidth/13) * CGFloat(i) + CenterX, y:0, width:charWidth/14, height:charWidth/12))
    textField.font =  UIFont(name: "Noteworthy", size: 50)
    textField.text = "\(characters[i])".lowercased()

    textField.textAlignment = .center
    textField.resizeText()
    textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    textField.minimumFontSize = 1.0
    textField.delegate = self

    textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    //textView.font = UIFont
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply use different method for a textField and firstly you take textField not a textView. All textFields have a its own outlets.

[How do I check when a UITextField changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-uitextfield-changes)

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

Here is the code for Swift 3 clickable textField:

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: .touchDown)
This is the function:

func myTargetFunction() {
    print("It works!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, please read my question carefully i want programmatically multiple textfield on middle of view. and yes i am using textField not textView

Comment: Try to follow link,i think it should also work with text: "NSAttributedString" 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift