# storing user-entered data from UITextField in String variable

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm having problems with the below code storing the right characters from user:  If the user enters "there" it stores "ther".

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String)
    -> Bool
{
    let text: String = nameInputText.text!
    //print(text) //this prints My text
    model.validateName(nametext: text)
    print(text)
    return true
}
```

I also have these functions for my keyboard hiding:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    nameInputText.resignFirstResponder()

    return (true)
}
```

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-uitextfield-changes) post.

Comment: Do you need to click and drag from storyboard for this one?

Answer (score 1):

Take note that `shouldChangeCharactersIn` is being called when user start input a character and it only can appear in `UITextField` when return true at the end of this method. (that is why your last input character not appear)

Thus, using `shouldChangeCharactersIn` is not the right way track your changes. use `UIControlEventEditingChanged` as suggested by @Rashwan