# Bug? UILabel live updating by UITextFieldDelegate is off by one character

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel, uitextfielddelegate

Here is a sample app to demonstrate the issue that I ran into:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var aTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var aTextLbl: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        aTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        aTextLbl.text = aTextField.text
        return true
    }
}
```

Here is a demo:

[Link to Animated Gif](https://giphy.com/gifs/liveupdateproblem-l0Iy0RICsnEYsIZ2M)

My question is, how to make it such that the label is exactly synced with what I type in the textfield? Thanks!

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-uitextfield-changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersIn`, you can use `EditingChanged` as follows.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var aTextLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var aTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        aTextLbl.text = aTextField.text
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you be a little more specific, I couldn't find a function that has the keyword "EditingChanged". Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried the "Value Changed" earlier today and it didn't work. But "Editing Changed" works really great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using UITextFieldDelegate function as well.

You need to manually append string with textField.text value like below:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentText = txtFldPassword.text
    let newText = (currentText! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    print(newText)

    return true
}
```