# How to update the text of a UILabel when the user fill in some Text Fields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I need to update a Label with the text the user has typed in some Text Field on the same Screen.
If possible I'd prefer to update it as the user types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change text in text field and label at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477776/how-to-change-text-in-text-field-and-label-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the textfield changes by adding a target for event UIControl.Event.editingChanged and update your label in the selector function. You can add target to the text field as follows.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

And in the objc function, you can update the label content.

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        label.text = textField.text
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible 
if you are using interface builder 
make a new `@IBAction` from your textField  like in the image 
[image] and choose `Editing Did Change`

```
  @IBAction func tfUpdate(_ sender: UITextField) {
        label.text = sender.text
    }
```