# How to check if textfield is empty in real time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I'm trying to change the appearance of my UIButton when the user has filled in both UITextFields, but I'm unable to get past a while loop. Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        FirstNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        FirstNameTextField.setBottomBorder()
        LastNameTextField.setBottomBorder()
        SignUpAndAccept.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        SignUpAndAccept.clipsToBounds = true
        SignUpAndAccept.isEnabled = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        test()
            }


        func test(){
        repeat {
            if ((LastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true) && (FirstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true)){
                SignUpAndAccept.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                SignUpAndAccept.isEnabled = false
                }
            else if((LastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? false) && (FirstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? false)) {
                SignUpAndAccept.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
                SignUpAndAccept.isEnabled = true
            }
        }while (SignUpAndAccept.isEnabled == false)
}
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28394933/3151675

Comment: variable names should be in camelCase.

Comment: @Adrian That's the programmer's decision, not a requirement. Although it is a good practice so that your style agrees with the majority of libraries out there and is more easily readable.

Comment: Thanks guys @Adrian willDo 

Comment: @ColGraff True.