# How to show entered data from UITextField to Label permanently?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel, func

I'm trying to make a function where when user enter a text in UITextField in the same moment label shows entered text.

How could I make it?

Like:

---

```
textField.text = "10"

Label.text = "\(textField.text) smthg" //. (10 smthg)
```

---

```
textField.text = "10.56"

Label.text = "\(textField.text) smthg" //. (10.56 smthg)
```

Comment: you can update the label in this textfield delegate method
`func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check when a UITextField changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-uitextfield-changes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and set it to `textField.delegate` property. From `UITextFieldDelegate` implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn` callback method that gets called everytime the user tries to change input in the textfield:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set the textField's delegate to self
        textField.delegate = self
    }

}

extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // to be always updated, you cannot use textField.text directly, because after this method gets called, the textField.text will be changed
        let newStringInTextField = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        yourLabel.text = "\(newStringInTextField) smthg"
        return true
    }
}
```

Using arguments of the function you can get a string that will appear in `textField` and you can set it as text in `yourLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `textfield`'s delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersIn`, it will be called when user start typing, delete a character from textfield, click on clear button appear at right side of textfield when there is text in textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Editing Changed` Action for that `textField`

```
@IBAction func changeText(_ sender: UITextField) {

     Label.text = "\(textField.text) smthg"
}
```