# How to display alert when the value of textfield is 0 in swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I want to display an alert when the value of textfield is 0.
However, putting a value of 0 in the textfield does not show the alert.

How can I solve the problem?

```
@IBOutlet var priceTextfield: UITextField!

if Int(priceTextfield.text!) == 0 {

   let aert = UIAlertController(title: "OK", message: "Price must be greater than 0.", preferredStyle: .alert)
   let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
   alert.addAction(OK)

   self.present(alert, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: can you add some additional detail.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-uitextfield-changes

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this is [`textFieldShouldEndEditing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619592-textfieldshouldendediting) delegate.

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if Double(textField.text!) == 0 {
        // Show alert
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**Note:** Your view controller needs to conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` and the text field delegate has to be set.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        priceTextfield.delegate = self
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you every time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.text.count > 1 {
     if let value = Int(textField.text), value == 0 { // Convert string to Int
                    // Show alert
         }
       }

     return true
  }
```

Comment: what the difference between your answer and shasthri answer

Comment: converted string to Int, Because Question was asked check with zero.

Comment: UItextField text property it is an optional String. You need to unwrap its value. `Int(textField.text!)`

Comment: Btw text has a default value of an empty string. Even if you assign nil before trying to access its value it will return `""`. So it is ok to force unwrap its value.