# UITextField background color change. Typing "blue" set the background to blue etc

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, background-color

I want to change myTextField background color to the color I type into the same myTextField. Here is my method:
and I also called this method in the viewDidLoad section: changeColor() but it doesn't work :(

```
func changeColor() {

    if myTextField.text == "blue" {
        myTextField.backgroundColor = .blue
    } else if myTextField.text == "red" {
        myTextfield.backgroundColor = .red
    } else {
        myTextField.backgroundColor = .black
    }
}
```

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

```
    if textField == myTextField {
        if range.location > 3 {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: And what's happening? `changeColor()` is called ONLY in `viewDidLoad()`? What's the value of `myTextField.text` then? Shouldn't you want to listen to text change and call `changeColor()` there? Did you look how to do so? By implementing `UITextFieldDelegate` methods?

Comment: UITextFieldDelegate is implemented, i can type anything, it appears in the textField. When the app starts, the textField is empty, and its background color is white(default), and when I type "blue" or "red" nothing happens, but i want the background color to be set to blue or red

Comment: @LászlóGábor have you implemented [`shouldChangeCharactersIn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631668/14351818)?

Comment: You don't call `changeColor()` in the corresponding `UITextFieldDelegate` method?  At start, it should be black indeed, instead of white though. Could you show more code?

Comment: yes I have, when i set the maximum character number

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == myTextField {
            if range.location > 3 {
                return false
            }
        }
       
        return true
    }

Comment: and it also works, i can type max 4 characters

Comment: @LászlóGábor can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67777368/edit) your question and show full code of `shouldChangeCharactersIn`?

Comment: But you don't call `changeColor()` inside that method? It's not because you called it in `viewDidLoad()` that it will be triggered each time, it's not bind with the textField. You need to call it each time you want to do so.

Comment: trying.... but somehow it doest show the way i wanted

Comment: ok so instead of calling "changeColor()" in the viewDidLoad, I should called it in the "shouldChangeCharactersIn" method?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extension for UITextField to add the changeColor function to the class (in any part of your code, it has to be outside classes). Then make an `objc` function to run the function of changing color. Finally, target the `objc` function to the textField with `.editingChanged` mode in `viewDidLoad()`.

The ViewController should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

    //Target function
    @objc func changeColor(_ sender:UITextField){
        sender.changeColor()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Add target
        myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeColor(_:)), for:      .editingChanged)
    }
}

//Extension to add function
extension UITextField{
    func changeColor() {
        if self.text == "blue" {
            self.backgroundColor = .blue
        } else if self.text == "red" {
            self.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = .black
        }
    }
}
```