# When modal is dismiss event

Tags: ios, xamarin

i have this code when i popup a modal in my `MainViewController`

```
ModalViewController controller = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("ModalViewController") as ModalViewController;
this.PresentViewController(controller,true,null);
```

and at the other end in my ModalViewController I have here an event where this will be dismiss. and I use this code. `DismissViewController(true,null);` is it possible that my MainViewController can catch the event when my modal is dismiss?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you need to use delegate pattern to handle it. if you are new to delegate then look here for [delegation in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the Xamarin pub/sub MessagingCenter: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/