# NSViewController delegate?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm new to using delegates in Swift, and I can't seem to figure out how to communicate with my View Controller from a different class. Specifically, I call the custom class's functions from my App Delegate, and then from within that custom class, I call a function within my View Controller. My basic setup, [following this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift), is:

AppDelegate.swift:

```
var customClass = customClass()
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    customClass.customFunction()
}
```

CustomClass.swift:

```
weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
func customFunction() {
    delegate?.delegateMethod(data)
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func customFunction(data: AnyObject)
}
class ViewController: NSViewController, ViewControllerDelegate
    func customFunction(data: AnyObject){
        println("called")
    }
}
```

However, `delegate` is always `nil`. I am assuming this is either because the `ViewControllerDelegate` protocol never gets initialized or because I never set the delegate of the actual `NSViewController`? I know I'm missing something obvious/straightfoward, however I have yet to see what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to answers because you have completely misunderstood the point of a protocol.

A protocol is a type which is used to define functionality. A class that conforms to this protocol provides the specified functionality, by implementing the required methods.

You can not initialize a protocol.

So if your CustomClass looks like this:

```
class CustomClass {
    weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
    func customFunction() {
        delegate?.delegateMethod(data)
    }
}
```

Why do you expect that `delegate` has suddenly a value?

Of course you have to set `delegate` to something first. The delegate must set `delegate`. If you want a ViewController instance to be the delegate, it must assign itself to `delegate`.

This for instance will work.

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate {
    func delegateMethod(data: AnyObject) //I renamed this because in   
    //CustomClass you are trying to call `delegateMethod` on the delegate
}
class CustomClass {
    weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
    func customFunction() {
        delegate?.delegateMethod(data)
    }
}
class ViewController: NSViewController, ViewControllerDelegate

    var customClass = CustomClass()

    func viewDidLoad(){
        customClass.delegate = self
        customClass.customFunction() 
    }

    func delegateMethod(data: AnyObject){
        println("called")
    }
}
```

Read more about [delegation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Comment: `you have completely misunderstood the point of a protocol` I apologize! Thanks for the answer though. One more question: if I initialize the custom class from the AppDelegate, what's the best way to get the already initialized instance of it in the ViewController when setting the delegate? As of now, since I initialize it in my AppDelegate as a variable, I reference it in my ViewController by `let customeClass = (NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).customClass` but this seems prone to failure...

Comment: @Charlie I already expected that question . It is possible (and not wrong) to reference the instance like you showed in your comment. But there are better ways (up to my opinion): Make CustomClass a singleton class; or declare a global variable above app delegate.

Comment: Would it be poor practice then to make a custom class `GlobalManager` that has something like `static let customClass = CustomClass()` in it, which I can then reference all the time?

Comment: @Charlie Not at all! But you don’t have to create a own class you can just create a global by putting `let customClass = CustomClass()` anywhere outside a class. However  your solution may be better because it protects against unintended shadowing of a global variable.