# Swift - Delegates - How do I link the protocol to the implemented delegate methods?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, delegates, protocols

I want to use a delegate to make my cells (from a UICollectionView) communicate with my ViewController.

In my Cell.swift file, I am declaring the protocol needed like this (outside the Cell class):

```
protocol CellDelegate: class {
    func someMethod(param1: String?, param2 param2: Bool)
}
```

In the same file I am declaring the delegate as follows:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
     weak var delegate: CellDelegate?

     // ... some code ...

     @IBAction func someAction(sender: AnyObject) {
             delegate?.someMethod(param1, param2: true)
     }
}
```

Now in my ViewController, I am implementing `someMethod`:

```
extension ViewController: CellDelegate {
     func someMethod(param1: String?, param2 param2: Bool) {

     // ... some code ...

     }
}
```

Problem : I can not link the protocol with its implementation, `cmd + click` in the protocol leads nowhere. In my `@IBAction`, `someMethod` is not crashing, but it does nothing.

I saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift) about the subject, but I do not understand where to implement the Step 6.

Can you help me ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the final step: populating the `delegate` property of the `Cell` class. I usually do that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCellId") as! Cell
    cell.delegate = self
    ...
    return cell
}
```

Note that there is no *magic* or automated behavior when using delegates:

- a delegate is a protocol (your `CellDelegate` protocol)
- you implement the protocol in the class you want to respond to the delegate invocations (you did in your `ViewController` class)
- you create a delegate property in the class where the delegate methods are invoked (you did in your `Cell` class)
- you initialize the delegate property with the actual instance of the class

You just missed the last step, leaving that property uninitialized, so any invocation using optional chaining evaluates to `nil` (like you did in the `someAction` method), and nothing happens.

Comment: On the `cell.delegate = self` part, Xcode tells me that I am assigning the wrong value type. I know that in Objective-C you can set the delegate to `id` to allow it to take any type in consideration. Do you have any idea of how doing it in Swift?

Comment: My guess is that the class doesn't implement the delegate protocol - is your `ViewController` implementing `CellDelegate`?

Comment: I set an extension on `ViewController`, as you can see on my original question. Maybe it would be better to implement it the classical way? I'll give it a try.

Comment: No it should work - I usually implement protocols via extensions. Can you show the actual compiler error message?

Comment: Here it is: `Cannot assign a value of type 'GridController' to a value of type 'CellDelegate?'`. I think I got it: I was calling the delegate in a controller which was not implementing `CellDelegate`, as you said before... I was confusing the two controllers. Thank you for your help, now it works ;-)