# Access to a ScrollView of a ViewController from another view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scrollview, subview

I actually work on a app in `Swift`.
I have my main `ViewController` with a `ScrollView` only.

In my swift file i add 3 view (3 subview controller) into the `ScrollView` in order to have a special navigation (horizontal navigation like a `View Pager`).

[image: The main ViewController with his subviews]

The problem is that each view has his swift file and therefore i don't find the solution to communicate with the `ScrollView` of the main `ViewController` from a `subview`.

For example a `SubViewController` (one of the three) have button on it.
And i would put a listener on this button and On click move the position of the screen in the `ScrollView` (which is on the main `view controller`), thanks to the method `setContentOffset` of the `scrollview`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `delegate` or an `NSNotificationCenter`
In order to pass a `notification`/`delegate` to other view in your case `UIScrollView`.
In you `UIScrollView` you should implement the delegation methods.
and Whooala, your `UIView` notified the `UIScrollView` of something you want it to know.

Here is example of the usage 
[Delegates in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift)

And here is some documentations
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

And a tutorial 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-delegation-and-properties--cms-23445

Comment: thanks ! i'm reading the second tutorial about delegation and properties.