# Call function from other ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiviewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers, `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. Both have an own Swift file, `FirstViewController.swift` and `SecondViewController.swift`.

`FirstViewController.swift` contains:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func callFunctionInOtherClass(sender: AnyObject) {
//        Call "func showAlert" in SecondViewController when clicking the UIButton in FirstViewController
    }
}
```

`SecondViewController.swift` contains:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    func showAlert(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Working!", message: "This function was called from FirstViewController!\nTextField says: \(textField.text!)", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call the `func showAlert()` in `SecondViewController` when taping on the `UIButton` in `FirstViewController`.

I've already spent many nights to find a solution but none worked. Does anybody know what to do to reach this goal?

I uploaded a sample Xcode project here: [CallFuntionInOtherClassX | filedropper.com](http://www.filedropper.com/callfuntioninotherclassx)

*P.S.: Of course, I could post some code and explain what error I get, but I think it's not reasonable because I really don't know how to do that.*

Comment: Why do you need this? Is this the exact use case (i.e. showing the alert)? If not, what is the actual use case?

Comment: Without allocating secondviewcontroller how can you call showAlert() method from firstviewcontroller?

Comment: use deleage or notification

Comment: @Losiowaty Not, it's not the exact use case. The real case is: I have a ViewController with two ContainerViews and I want to be able to e.g. submit a form filled in a ContainerView by taping a button in the Main/Parent-ViewController, because it has the navigation buttons, title…

Comment: @Poles I'm not very experienced in programming. Maybe you can help me, please?

Comment: @Shobhakar Tiwari What does it exactly mean? Do you have an example or so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25792213/3400991 here is the link try this way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `NSNotificationCentre` to accomplish this task.

In `viewDidLoad` method of your `SecondViewController` class register self as observer to receive notification broadcasts:-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAlert), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "callForAlert"), object: nil)
}
```

and in `FirstViewController`'s button action method you should fire the notification by writing :-

```
@IBAction func callFunctionInOtherClass(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Call "func showAlert" in SecondViewController when clicking the UIButton in FirstViewController
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "callForAlert"), object: nil)
}
```

Don't forget to call `removeObserver` in SecondViewController's `viewDidUnload` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works and saved me hours. But still two questions: `1.` What do you mean with your last sentence? What does this do? `2.` Why are you the only one who suggested this solution? Is it an uncommon way? Because, it seems very easy. I'm wondering why not any other had this idea.

Comment: Shobhakar Tiwari also suggested the standard ways of implementing target action mechanism . But your specified case can't be handled by delegates leaving only one option i.e. NotificationCentre. and as per apple documentation : Be sure to invoke this method (or removeObserver:) before the observer object or any object specified in addObserver:selector:name:object: is deallocated. Because it might crash your app when notification is called on nil observer.

Comment: It Also have memory leak implications.

Comment: Sorry, but NSNotificationCenter for ordinary communication between objects is the wrong decision for 99 % of the time.

Comment: Yes Eiko, but his use case doesn't qualify for delegate or Block implementations. And can you please explain why shouldn't we use in the scenario mentioned above and according to you what should be the correct way to achieve the solution of above question ?

Comment: @Eiko I don't think this answer deserves a Downvote, You may have other options but rather down voting you should suggest a better answer, I can see u are a huge contributor to the SO community, as the Owner of this question has already accepted the answer.

Comment: Similar question get asked here over and over again - it should have been closed as a duplicate right away. I see no reason why delegates or blocks wouldn't work here, or why storing a reference to the other controller as a simple property and calling a method on that would fail. The notification approach is like ordering in a fast food restaurant and waiting for someone to shout "Food is ready for pickup" - yes, it could work, and without a name, it might even reach recipient at first try...

Comment: I agree, storing a reference to the other controller as a simple property and calling a method on that stored property is good option.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: These functions have been revised in swift 3 as follows:

**Code in FirstViewController**

```
 override function viewDidLoad(){
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAlert), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showAlert"), object: nil)
}
```

**Code in SecondViewController:**

```
@IBAction func callFunctionInOtherClass(sender: AnyObject) {
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showAlert"), object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SecondViewController().showAlert(self)
```

In your second view controller

```
 if let text = textField?.text {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

      let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Working!", message: "This function was called from FirstViewController!\nTextField says: \(text)", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
      alert.show()

    })
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and it crashes. But when removing the alert code and just doing a `print("It works!")` there's no crash and I get the print in the console.

Comment: `\(textField.text!)` seems to be the problem. When removing it, it works, with and without `dispatch_async`. Any ideas what do to?

Comment: First check does it really hold text then use else not

Comment: I don't think it'll help because if textField empty it also shows an empty string, not an error message. Or, am I wrong?

Comment: :) read the crash message dear. found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: What you say sounds reasonable. I'll try it.

Comment: Is that the right way? Code:`if (textField.text == "") {`
            `let myString = textField`
        `}`
        `else {`
            `let myString : String = "empty"`
        `}` And `\(myString.text)` in the alert. Because I get: `Use of unresolved identifier 'myString'`

Comment: It may work but lengthy. Try the edit if it fits you

Comment: You can use if let text = textField.text  inside the main queue their to fit for empty string

Comment: Unfortunately still the same: Crash and `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)`

Comment: give me some time plz

Comment: Does your outlet looks like this?  @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!`

Comment: Still trying something. I'll reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show alert view to `second viewcontroller` from `firstview controller` when go to it you can do something like,

```
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("your segue identifier", sender: self)  // or whatever way if you are not using storyboard or segue

    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Working!", message: "This function was called from FirstViewController!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
    alert.show()
```

If you want to set any `variables` of `secondviewcontroller` then you need to implement `prepareForSegue` method.  (if you are using segue).

Second thing you can show alertview in `viewDidload` of `secondViewController` also.

Comment: Unfortunately won't work. I need this function executed it `SecondViewController` because I'll need `@IBOutlet's` for it's `ViewController`.