# Reach function in another viewcontroller file?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a popupviewcontroller using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgCIRMz_3dE

And I would like when I press down the popup (with a Retry-button instead), that it should go back to the original Viewcontroller, as it does, but also restarts the "game" on the original viewcontroller automatically. So basically I want to start the game when I press "Retry" on the popup. But I only get errors when trying to reach that function..

Original Viewcontroller:

```
var time : Float = 0.0
    var timer: NSTimer?


    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startGame()
    }
    func startGame() {
        startTimer()

    }
    func startTimer() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector:#selector(GameViewController.setProgress1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    func setProgress1() {
        time += 0.001
        progressBar.setProgress(time / 2, animated: true)
        if time >= 1.9 {
            endPopUp()
            timer!.invalidate()
            progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
            setProgress1(time = 0.0)

        }
    }


    func endPopUp() {
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("endPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)



        }



}
```

As you can see, when the time reaches 1.9, the popOverVC should appear, but when the popup closes with the button in the popOverVC, I want to type:
GameViewController().startGame()

But it's just giving me errors... how do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift

Comment: I know what a delegate is, kind of. But I need help how to use it for this scenario. So a bit more detailed help would mean a lot.

Comment: Thanks, but Im going to need a little more help than that :/ Guess I will need to look somewhere else

Comment: If you post a question about errors in your code, you need to include those errors in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the swift guy, but the underneath concept is same for objective-c and swift. **Code examples are in objective-c**.

**TODO:**
Declare a `protocol` in your `popOverViewContorller` header file. As your state, you need to protocol method as following

```
@protocol PopOverViewControllerDelegate
    -(void)popOverRetryBtnPressed;
    -(void)popOverCloseBtnPressed;
@end
```

In your header file declare a property as follows

```
@interface PopOverViewController:UIIViewController
    ...//other staff
    @property id<PopOverViewControllerDelegate> myDelegate;
@end
```

Now in your retry button action should look something like this

```
-(IBAction)onPressRetry:(id)sender
{
    if(self.myDelegate && [self.myDelegate respondToSelector:@selector(popOverRetryBtnPressed)])
    {
         [self.myDelegate popOverRetryBtnPressed];
    }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"delegate not implemented");
    }
}
```

simillarly complete the `close` button function. Now implement the delegates in your view controller as any other delegate. Don't forget to set the `popOverViewController`'s `myDelegate` property.

**Under the hood:** 
Here is what happens when a delegate pattern is used. When a `protocol` is declared, it's contain the information that, what the object is capable of providing while implement this protocol. Say in the above example, our protocol is saying that, the object that will conform this protocol will contain two function named `popOverRetryBtnPressed` & `popOverCloseBtnPressed`. Then we declare an property of type `id<PopOverViewControllerDelegate>` which denote any class that conform to the protocol declaration `PopOverViewControllerDelegate`. Setting this property will contain the reference to the object which conform and implement the delegate method. Now time to call these protocol methods in appropriate places. In retry button action call the `popOverRetryBtnPressed`, and call `popOverCloseBtnPressed` as in same manner. Now before calling check is that `self.myDelegate` object actually implements any method which you are calling, Otherwise it will end up crashing.

Thats all, hope you enjoy it.