# Passing Values to WKWebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am attempting to pass a users interaction from a popOver view to ViewController to then interact with WKWebView.

Currently the popOver has Buttons which when selected calls
`ViewController().callViewControllerMethod()`
this method works correctly and does call `callViewControllerMethod()`.

Within `callViewControllerMethod()` is some code to evaluateJavascript on a WKWebView. When the code is ran it hits the `evaluateJavascript` code and throws  `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

But I have no idea why - the javascript that is within the `evaluateJavascript` function works correctly if called directly from `ViewController`, but only if called directly.

Any ideas anyone?

PopOver Code

```
class BackgroundViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func button1(_ sender: AnyObject!) {
        print("button 1 selected")
        ViewController().callViewControllerMethod()
    }
}
```

ViewController Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func callViewControllerMethod() {
        print("got to the method")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.background = \"white\";") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(result as Any)
            }
            else {
                print("background code completed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample demonstrating exactly where the problem occurs.

Comment: "But I have no idea why" - the compiler unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. This is the best answer you will get without providing any code from the context :/

Comment: sorry does help if i add some code ;)

Answer (score 0):

This `ViewController().callViewControllerMethod()` is why you get the error, you are basically create new instance of `ViewController` and tell it to do something, it's not the same as the current `ViewController` instance you have

To fix your problem, you have to create a protocol/delegate on the `PopOver` to tell the `ViewController` to execute `callViewControllerMethod` from itself

Comment: okay thanks that makes sense why I'm getting nil  - do you know where i can look for how to do delegate? - Im a new to Swift :/

Comment: There are many tutorial for that, you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift) or [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/)