# Swift 3 : Delegate within TapGestureRecognizer in Generics doesn't get called

Tags: swift, generics, delegates

I have a protocol like so :

```
public  protocol SubmitAgeDelegate : class  {
func changeSubmitButtonBool()
}
```

The problem is I want to call it in a generics class.

```
open class GenericController<UICollectionViewCell,UICollectionReusableView> {

weak var submitAgeDelegate: SubmitAgeDelegate?
```

Within a UITapGestureRecognizer

```
func tapGestureDidRecognize(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let myAgeDelegate = self.submitAgeDelegate {
        print("inside delegate")   //Never gets inside
        myAgeDelegate.changeSubmitButtonBool() 
    }

}
```

Not too sure why it never gets called? Similar ways have worked in regular classes withing IBAction functions.

In my other class :

```
open class MyCell: ActionCell, SubmitAgeDelegate {
weak var submitAgeDelegate: SubmitAgeDelegate?    

public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    submitAgeDelegate  = self
    initialize()
}

// Delegate 
public func changeSubmitButtonBool(){

    print("called ")
}
```

Comment: Did you ever set `submitAgeDelegate` anywhere? If you did then please include that code. If you didn't then that's your problem.

Comment: Hello Suragch, thanks for your insights, I have posted my addition to the code, basically the thing is I do not have any relation to the delegating class , so I do not have an instance of that class that might sell its delegate.
Somethinglike GenericController.delegate = self within MyCell's viewdidLoad for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never setting the `submitAgeDelegate` of the `GenericController`. Having a member of the same name in your `MyCell` class doesn't help.

You need to get a reference to your `GenericController` in order to set its delegate; there's no way around that. (This doesn't have anything to do with generics; it's the same for non-generic classes.) Since it looks like you're using it as a `UICollectionViewCell`, you might use the reference that you make in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or similar.

Comment: Yes I wanted to basically induce the delegate being called without creating an instance, but "You need to get a reference to your GenericController in order to set its delegate; there's no way around that." makes it clear I will have to get that instance somehow. Thank you so much!