# I am trying to using a custom delegate in swift but when I want to call its methods, it did not get called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have been searching for how the delegate works and I tried to do it in my project. Unfortunately, the delegate method I implement does not get called ever. I am trying to do a slide-out navigation panel. so what I did is that I put two uicontainerviews, one is for slide-out navigation panel and the other for main view controller 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1EbT.png)

The code is that 
For main view controller

```
protocol MainViewControllerDelegate {
    func toggleSideMenu()
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: MainViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Slide Action

    @IBAction func slideMenuTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        delegate?.toggleSideMenu()
        print("Slide Menu has been tapped")
    }
}
```

For container view controller

```
class ContainerVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var SideMenuConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var slideMenuContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainViewContainer: UIView!

    var mainViewController: MainViewController?

    var isSideMenuOpened = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainViewController = UIStoryboard.mainViewController()
        mainViewController?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ContainerVC: MainViewControllerDelegate{
    func toggleSideMenu() {
        print("It works")
        if isSideMenuOpened{
            isSideMenuOpened = false
            SideMenuConstraint.constant = -260
            mainViewContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        } else {
            isSideMenuOpened = true
            SideMenuConstraint.constant = 0
            mainViewContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.59
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

extension UIStoryboard{
    static func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main) }
    static func mainViewController() -> MainViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController
    }
}
```

Please let know what's wrong

Comment: i think you haven't initialized the delegate property.

Comment: How do I initialize it?

Comment: Refer to this link for more info about how to declare a delegate in swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792213/1091539

Comment: initialize it like this, delegate = MainViewControllerDelegate()

Comment: @Mutawe Should I use prepare for segue in my case?

Comment: @Ashik I did that but I got this error "'MainViewControllerDelegate' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers"

Comment: I am sorry, my previous comment was wrong. Really sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that you embed your main view controller in navigation controller :

```
let navigationController = self.childViewControllers.last as! UINavigationController
let mainViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! MainViewController
mainViewController?.delegate = self
```

Comment: Yup, that is right. I tried it and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you got wrong:

```
mainViewController = UIStoryboard.mainViewController()
mainViewController?.delegate = self
```

this `mainViewController` is not the same as the child of the container view controller, so setting *its* delegate doesn't really do anything.

You need to first get the VC that is the child of the container view controller:

```
mainViewController = self.childViewControllers.last as! MainViewController
mainViewController.delegate = self
```

Comment: @FaisalAlkhotaifi Sorry, I thought your container is a child of a parent, fixed now.