# how to pass Values from ViewController to UITableView custom cell class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols

i have a VC name `RestaurantViewController` it has custom cell for itemName ItemPrice and there are three button + , - and add their actions are in customCellClass now when a user select the quantity by setting with plus/minus and then hit the add button the whole data should go to the `CartVC` but not push until user selects the cart icon on main menu.

the `RestaurantVC` looks like this[image]

currently i'm using the blockClosure to pass data

```
 //assign item name to cell
    let selectedDictName = restMenu[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    print("the selected dict ", selectedDictName)
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = selectedDictName.value(forKey: "ItemName") as! String

    // assign item price to cell
    let selectedDictPrice = restMenu[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    cell.itemPriceLabel.text = "Price: \(selectedDictPrice.value(forKey: "ItemPrice") as! String)"

    // pass ItemName and ItemPrice by blockClosure
    if blockClosure != nil{
        blockClosure(selectedDictName.value(forKey: "ItemName") as! String, selectedDictPrice.value(forKey: "ItemPrice") as! String )
    }
```

but this pass all values corresponding the selected restaurant at before loading the cell

how can i pass data and then further attach the item quantity with it? it will be very helpful for my final semester project

Comment: Are you familiar with protocols and delegate?
Give this a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792213/4427884

Comment: You want pass data from `RestaurantViewController` to custom cell? I think you are already doing by setting `cell.itemNameLabel.text`.. Can you explain your problem little more?

Comment: with this cell.itemNameLabel.text the last object value in dictionary is assigned to the closure block not the one whose button is clicked

Comment: Shouldn't the question be 'passing values form custom tableViewCell to ViewController'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow Below Code:- Using Protocol Delegate

```
//1
//Create protocol

protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func addTapped(cell: TableViewCell)
}

//2
//Create instance
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?

….

@IBAction func addAction(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.addTapped(cell: self)
}
}


//3

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “cell”, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
}

 //4
extension ViewController: TableViewCellDelegate {
func addTapped(cell: TableViewCell) {

 }
}
```

Comment: Follow these four steps, you will come to how to use protocol and delegate, and you will get idea how to deal with your problem

Comment: can i send the data using cell.blockClosure ? for the corresponding cell where the add button pressed to send the data to add button method and further attached to NSDictionary?

Comment: When you hit the + - button you can get here 4th step, look above answer... and in addTapped action you can update your dictionary and reload tableview

Comment: you need to take + and - button action in tableviewcell and need to take one extra method in Protocol and conform all mehod to View controller

Comment: i'll try this and notify you as soon as possible

Comment: its working but now how to get the data from corresponding cell like itemName and ItemPrice?

Comment: how get the indexPath for the func addTapped(cell: TableViewCell)

Comment: let indexPath = self.yourTableview.indexPath(for: cell)  To get Indexpath

Comment: very helpful @Manish Mahajan Bro