# Not works NMANavigationManagerDelegate in HERE Map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I'm using the HERE iOS SDK and I'm implementing a turn-by-turn navigation but method `didUpdateManeuvers` of `NMANavigationManagerDelegate` or any else is not called.

When I try to simulate move and use:

```
let source = NMARoutePositionSource(route: route.route)
NMAPositioningManager.sharedInstance().dataSource = source
```

all works fine, but when I simulate move through `GPX` file or test in live, methods of delegate is not called...

My code:

```
class HereMapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var mapView: NMAMapView!

    fileprivate var navigationManager = NMANavigationManager.sharedInstance()
    var route : NMAMapRoute?


    // MARK: - life cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupUI()
    }

    deinit {
        navigationManager.stop()
    }


    // MARK: - private

    private func setupUI() {
        mapView.copyrightLogoPosition = .center
        mapView.zoomLevel = 10
        mapView.positionIndicator.isVisible = true
        mapView.gestureDelegate = self
        navigationManager.voicePackageMeasurementSystem = NMAMeasurementSystem.imperialUS
        navigationManager.backgroundNavigationEnabled = true
        navigationManager.isVoiceEnabled = true

        navigationManager.delegate = self
        setupRoute()
    }

    private func setupRoute() {
        guard let mapRoute = route, let routeStart = mapRoute.route.start else {
                return
        }

        let start = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: routeStart.navigablePosition.latitude,
                                      longitude: routeStart.navigablePosition.longitude)

        mapView.add(mapObject: mapRoute)
        mapView.set(boundingBox: mapRoute.route.boundingBox!, animation: NMAMapAnimation.none)

        startNavigation()
        mapView.set(geoCenter: start, animation: .none)
    }
    private func startNavigation() {
        guard let route = route else {
            return
        }

        navigationManager.map = mapView
        NMAPositioningManager.sharedInstance().dataSource = NMAHEREPositionSource()
        navigationManager.startTurnByTurnNavigation(route.route)
        navigationManager.mapTrackingEnabled = false
        navigationManager.mapTrackingAutoZoomEnabled = false
        navigationManager.mapTrackingOrientation = .dynamic
        navigationManager.isSpeedWarningEnabled = true

    }
}


//MARK: - NMANavigationManagerDelegate

extension HereMapViewController : NMANavigationManagerDelegate {
    // Signifies that there is new instruction information available
    func navigationManager(_ navigationManager: NMANavigationManager, didUpdateManeuvers currentManeuver: NMAManeuver?, _ nextManeuver: NMAManeuver?) {
        print("didUpdateManeuvers")
    }

    // Signifies that the system has found a GPS signal
    func navigationManagerDidFindPosition(_ navigationManager: NMANavigationManager) {
        print("New position has been found")
    }

    func navigationManager(_ navigationManager: NMANavigationManager, didFindAlternateRoute routeResult: NMARouteResult) {
        print("didFindAlternateRoute")
    }

    func navigationManager(_ navigationManager: NMANavigationManager, didUpdateRoute routeResult: NMARouteResult) {
        print("didUpdateRoute")
    }
}


//MARK: - NMAMapGestureDelegate

extension HereMapViewController : NMAMapGestureDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: NMAMapView, didReceiveTwoFingerPan translation: CGPoint, at location: CGPoint) {
        navigationManager.mapTrackingAutoZoomEnabled = false
    }
}
```

I want to track, when I should change manoeuvre or when I need to create a new route if user went the wrong way. I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet works for me. Make sure you don't get any console errors:

```
Access to this operation is denied.
```

or

```
This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain both “NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription” and “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription” keys with string values explaining to the user how the app uses this data
```

[NMAHEREPositionSource](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAHEREPositionSource.html) requires [NSMotionUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsmotionusagedescription) key to be set in Info.plist. You can check if [NMADevicePositionSource](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMADevicePositionSource.html) works for you.

To simulate movement with GPX file, use [NMALoggedPositionSource](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMALoggedPositionSource.html)

To force positioning broadcast, you can use [startPositioning](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAPositioningManager.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAPositioningManager(im)startPositioning)

Comment: Thanks, when I use NMADevicePositionSource all works

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you set your class properly to receive delegate behavior.

Check out this question's answers, particularly the second one from MakeAppPie. [Delegates in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift)

Make sure you have followed all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss this line

```html
navigationManager.setTrafficAvoidanceMode(.manual)
```

I have the same problem :/