# How to trigger/call a function from another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function named deleteCartItemCell() in CartVC view controller. From CartVC i am presenting a view controller named ConfirmPopUpVC. My question is how can i call/trigger deleteCartItemCell() function from ConfirmPopUpVC.

deleteCartItemCell() function:-

```
func deleteCartItemCell(row:Int){
    cartVM.removeCart(itemType: cartList[row].itemType, itemId: cartList[row].itemId)
        .subscribe(onSuccess: { (response) in
            self.toast(response.message)
            if response.status{
                self.observerCartResponse()
                self.tblCartList.reloadData()
            }
        }) { (error) in
            self.toast(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        .disposed(by: cartVM.disposeBag)
}
```

Presenting the ConfirmPopUpVC view controller this way:

```
func customPresent<T>(storyBoardIdentifier: String = "Main",animate: Bool = true, attacher: (T) -> Void = { _ in  } ) -> T where T: UIViewController{
    let destVc: T
    destVc = instantiateViewController(storyBoardIdentifier: storyBoardIdentifier)
    destVc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    destVc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
    attacher(destVc)
    self.tabBarController?.present(destVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return destVc
}
```

I tried to call deleteCartItemCell() function from ConfirmPopUpVC by creating an object but encountered this error:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delegates in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift)

Comment: https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/ Read this too.

Comment: I tried delegation too but it is showing this error: - Property 'delegate' with type 'delegateFromCartVC.Protocol' cannot override a property with type 'AppDelegate'

Comment: Use a different name. Include your code if it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the delegate pattern to define a delegate class in your 'destVc'. This way you can notify the presenting ViewController by calling a delegate method. (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID276)
- You can define a callback closure on the 'destVc' ViewController, so you only need to call that from the presented ViewController once it's done with its job (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)
- You can use NotificationCenter to notify any object which is observing notifications with a given Identifier (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter)

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function using closure.

1 - Create completion block into **ConfirmPopUpVC**

`var completion: (()->Void)? = nil`

2 - implement it when you present view controller

`vc.completion = { // write your code here }`

3 - call it from the **ConfirmPopUpVC** when you execute code

`completion?()`