# How to dismiss modal and performSegue at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift

I am not fluent in English. Sorry...

I have a modalView with collectionView. I use didselect function. If I select a cell, the modalView will dismiss, and want to move originView -> newView.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "NewView", sender: nil)
}
```

It dose not work. Just dismiss not performSegue.
How should I do

Comment: Your design makes no sense. You dismiss (throw away) the view which is supposed to be the source of the segue. You should connect the segue from the **parent** view of the modal view and use a callback in the `completion` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a segue between your OriginViewController and NewViewController then perform the segue after dismissing the CollectionViewController.

Segue: **[OriginViewController]** *--NewViewSegue-->* **[NewViewController]**

```
class OriginViewController: UIViewController {

}

class NewViewController: UIViewController {
    
}

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
          // presentingViewController is your OriginViewController
          let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController
          // change animated parameter to false if you need to skip the dismiss animation
          self.dismiss(animated: true) {
              presentingVC?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NewViewSegue", sender: nil)
          }
     }
}
```

Sample

[image]

Another method is you can use a delegate on dismiss completion.
How to use a [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37203430/11662833).