# How to get the touch coordinates from a valueChanged event in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrolevents

**Background**

I've [previously learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34764356/3681880) how to use a Gesture Recognizer or `continueTrackingWithTouch` to get continuous updates of the current touch location and to then use those to do something like this:

[image]

Now, however, I would like to learn how to do the same thing using targets. I can already get the touch down and touch up events by using `TouchDown` and `TouchUpInside`, but I don't know how to get the continuous updates. I assumed that it would be using the `ValueChanged` event, but so far that isn't working.

**This is what I have tried:**

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomControl: MyCustomControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var trackingBeganLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var trackingEndedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var xLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // these work
        myCustomControl.addTarget(self, action: "myTouchDown", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        myCustomControl.addTarget(self, action: "myTouchUpInside", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        // this doesn't work
        myCustomControl.addTarget(self, action: "myValueChangedEvent:",
            forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    // this works
    func myTouchDown() {
        trackingBeganLabel.text = "Touched down"
    }

    // this works
    func myTouchUpInside() {
        trackingEndedLabel.text = "Touch up inside"
    }

    // this doesn't work, function never gets called
    func myValueChangedEvent(sender: UIControl) { 
        let location = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: myCustomControl) 
        xLabel.text = "x: \(location.x)"
        yLabel.text = "y: \(location.y)"
    }
}
```

*MyCustomControl.swift*

```
import UIKit
class MyCustomControl: UIControl {
    // currently empty. Do I need to add something here?
}
```

**Notes**

- Changed the code after getting @CaseyWagner's answer. The compiler doesn't throw an error anymore but `UIControlEvents.ValueChanged` never gets fired.
- This question is my attempt to have a complete answer for the **Method 1: Adding a Target** section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34764356/3681880).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside` instead of `UIControlEvents.ValueChanged` (also notice that action method receives two arguments):

```
myCustomControl.addTarget(self, action: "didDragInsideControl:withEvent:",
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)
```

The handler function looks like this:

```
func didDragInsideControl(control: MyCustomControl, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = event.touchesForView(control)!.first!
    let location = touch.locationInView(control)
    xLabel.text = "x: \(location.x)"
    yLabel.text = "y: \(location.y)"
}
```

Comment: Great! I had missed the `TouchDragInside` event. I used `if let touch = ...` because I'm not sure if the forced unwrapping would ever cause a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it looks like you might need:

```
 let location = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: myCustomControl)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Comment `@UIApplicationMain` line in `AppDelegate`
2. Create new file with name main.swift and add this code in that file

   ```
   import UIKit
   import Foundation
   UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, NSStringFromClass(AppClass), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
   ```
3. Create New class with name "AppClass" and subclass of UIApplication
4. Write following code in that method
       import UIKit

   ```
   class AppClass: UIApplication {
       override func sendEvent(event: UIEvent)
       {
           super.sendEvent(event)
           print("send event") // this is an example
           // ... dispatch the message...
        }   
   }
   ```
5. Here, in sendEvent method, you will get all the events happening in application(all screens), all touch events, so here you can use this UIEvent and perform any task if you want